# Existence of Bounded Linear Functional That Maps Elements of Normed Space to Distance from Subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm attempting to prove the following:

> Suppose X is a normed space and Y a subspace of X. Let $x ∈ X$ and denote $d$ the distance from $x$ to $Y$; that is, $d = d(x, Y ) = \inf_{y∈Y} || x − y ||$. Prove that there exists a bounded linear functional $f : X → R$ such that
>   $f(x) = d$, $f(y) = 0$, for all $y ∈ Y$ and $||f||_{op} = \sup_{x \in X, ||x||=1}||fx|| ≤ 1$.

It seems like this can be proven using the Hahn-Banach Theorem, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That is a consequence of Hanh-Banach theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $d>0$.  Otherwise, the zero functional trivially solves the problem.

We apply Hahn-Banach Theorem on the subspace $\mathrm{span}\{Y,x\}=\{tx+y\in X\mid t\in \Bbb{R},y\in Y\}$ and the functional $g:\mathrm{Y,span}\{x\}\to\Bbb{R},g(tx+y)=t||x||=||tx||$ linear with respect to $t$ and $y$.  Check that $g(x) = ||x||$.  For any unit vector $u\in\mathrm{span}\{Y,x\},$ express $u$ as $tx+y$
$$|g(u)| = \left|g\left(\frac{tx+y}{||tx+y||}\right)\right|=\frac{|t|\,||x||}{||tx+y||}  = \frac{||x||}{||x-(-y/|t|)||}\le \frac{||x||}{d},$$ so $||g||_{(\mathrm{span}\{Y,x\})'} \le ||x||/d$.  (The last inequality makes use of the defintion of $d$ as $\inf\limits_{y \in Y} ||x-y||$, $Y$ as a subspace of $X$, and the assumption $d>0$.)

By Hahn-Banach, there exists a bounded functional $f(\in X')$ extending $g$ to the whole space $X$: $$||f||_{X'}= ||g||_{(\mathrm{span}\{Y,x\})'} \le \frac{||x||}{d} \text{ and } f(z) = g(z) \quad\forall\, z\in\mathrm{span}\{Y,x\}.$$

In particular, $f(x)=||x||$.  We scale this function $f$ by a factor of $d/||x||$ to finish the proof.

Comment: I'm following up until the $\frac{d}{||x||} = 1$ bit. Why is this true? This step is to prove that $g$ is bounded, correct?

Comment: @OGBerglemir I'm going to fix it.  You are right.

Comment: It might be a little late, but I just saw this which is realted to a question I have. I don't understand the last step in the estimate of $|g(u)|$: This is not true for general norms right? For example $|-2|/|-2+1|=2>1$. So how do you get that your term is smaller or equal to 1?

Comment: @mathstackuser Thanks for your comment and spotting out this error.  I've edited my question to address the problem in the first comment.